# mysqli_real_connect(): MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to start xampp v3.2.4 from windows 10 64 bit. I am getting the error shown in the image [error page while connecting mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u24EZ.png)

[xampp log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owhqg.png)

1. I deleted the ibdata1,ib_logfile1,ib_logfile0 from sql data folder restarted xampp and system
2. Changed the values in config file

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Below is my log file

```
2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 1604020; transaction id 9

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190927 10:05:28

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2019-09-27 10:05:28 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Change the packet size `max_allowed_packet = 64M` in my.ini and it will solve the problems

my.ini file located at `Xampp controlpanel > mysql > config > my.ini`